# Calling a Jquery pop up window from a Google Maps Marker

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps-api-3

I am currently using the Jquery Colorbox as a popup window, calling it from a button in HTML as follows:

```
<a class='inline' id="button1" href="#inline_content">Need Help? Click Me</a>
```

Which then displays content which is hidden in this div:

```
<div id='inline_content' style='padding:10px; background:#fff;'>
```

I am using Google Maps to display a full screen map and have generated markers through JavaScript which works fine like this:

```
var image = 'images/pin-yellow-2.png';
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
position: myLatlng,
map: map,
title: 'I am a Custom Pin!',
icon: image
}),
```

but I would like to call Colorbox Jquery from the HTML using a marker on the map through JavaScript, any ideas on how I would go about this?

Comment: If you want to open the colorbox by clicking the map marker, then register the 'click' event on that custom marker, and call the colorbox from there.

Comment: Thanks for the response Eric, I should have pointed out that my coding really isn't very good; I understand that I should be using something along the lines of the following in the Javascript, but I am not sure what should go in the function :

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
  });